# How to generate direct access keys to nested hash which contains hash and arrays as values?

Tags: ruby

I want to compare two XML files where one is input and the other is output. I am converting both into a hash.

My idea is to get all the keys from the input XML converted to hash, and search each key in both the input and output hashes for their respective key/value pairs.

I have a hash:

```
{
  "requisition_header" => {
    "requested_by" => {"login" => "coupasupport"},
    "department" => {"name" => "Marketing"},
    "ship_to_address" => {"name" => "Address_1431693296"},
    "justification" => nil,
    "attachments" => [],
    "requisition_lines" => [
      {
        "description" => "Cleaning Services for Building A",
        "line_num" => 1,
        "need_by_date" => 2010-09-23 07:00:00 UTC,
        "source_part_num" => nil,
        "supp_aux_part_num" => nil,
        "unit_price" => #<BigDecimal:a60520c,'0.3E4',9(18)>,
        "supplier" => {"name" => "amazon.com"},
          "account" => {
          "code" => "SF-Marketing-Indirect",
          "account_type" => {"name" => "Ace Corporate"}
        },
        "currency" => {"code" => "USD"},
        "payment_term" => {"code" => "Net 30"},
        "shipping_term" => {"code" => "Standard"},
        "commodity" => {"name" => "Marketing-Services"}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is nested and all the values are not directly accessible.

I want a way to generate direct access to each value in the hash.

For example:

```
requisition_header.requested_by.login
```

will access "coupasupport".

```
requisition_header.department.name
```

will access "Marketing".

```
requisition_header.requisition_lines[0].description
```

will access "Cleaning Services for Building A".

```
requisition_header.requisition_lines[0].line_num
```

will access "1".

```
requisition_header.requisition_lines[0].need_by_date
```

will access "2010-09-23 07:00:00 UTC".

Each key built can be used to search for the value directly inside the hash.

Comment: Your sample hash is way too big. When providing sample data, reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything longer and you waste our time, delaying our ability to help you.

Answer (score 3):

That could be done with the following method, that translates the nested hash into nested [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)s:

```
require 'ostruct'
def deep_structify(hash)
  result = {}
  hash.each do |key, value|
    result[key] = value.is_a?(Hash) ? deep_structify(value) : value
  end if hash
  OpenStruct.new(result)
end

hash = {"requisition_header"=>{"requested_by"=>{"login"=>"coupasupport"}, "department"=>{"name"=>"Marketing"}, "ship_to_address"=>{"name"=>"Address_1431693296"}, "justification"=>nil, "attachments"=>[], "requisition_lines"=>[{"description"=>"Cleaning Services for Building A", "line_num"=>1, "need_by_date"=>2010-09-23 07:00:00 UTC, "source_part_num"=>nil, "supp_aux_part_num"=>nil, "unit_price"=>#<BigDecimal:a60520c,'0.3E4',9(18)>, "supplier"=>{"name"=>"amazon.com"}, "account"=>{"code"=>"SF-Marketing-Indirect", "account_type"=>{"name"=>"Ace Corporate"}}, "currency"=>{"code"=>"USD"}, "payment_term"=>{"code"=>"Net 30"}, "shipping_term"=>{"code"=>"Standard"}, "commodity"=>{"name"=>"Marketing-Services"}}]}}

struct = deep_structify(hash)

struct.requisition_header.department.name
#=> "Marketing"
```

Comment: Thank you, I wrote that code months ago for my [has_configuration](https://github.com/spickermann/has_configuration/blob/master/lib/has_configuration/configuration.rb#L65) gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding [OpenStruct#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-c-new) as well,

```
require 'ostruct'

class DeepStruct < OpenStruct
  def initialize(hash=nil)
    @table = {}
    @hash_table = {}

    if hash
      hash.each do |k,v|
        @table[k.to_sym] = (v.is_a?(Hash) ? self.class.new(v) : v)
        @hash_table[k.to_sym] = v

        new_ostruct_member(k)
      end
    end
  end

  def to_h
    @hash_table
  end

end
```

Now you can do:

```
require 'deep_struct'

hash = {"requisition_header"=>{"requested_by"=>{"login"=>"coupasupport"}, "department"=>{"name"=>"Marketing"}, "ship_to_address"=>{"name"=>"Address_1431693296"}, "justification"=>nil, "attachments"=>[], "requisition_lines"=>[{"description"=>"Cleaning Services for Building A", "line_num"=>1, "need_by_date"=>2010-09-23 07:00:00 UTC, "source_part_num"=>nil, "supp_aux_part_num"=>nil, "unit_price"=>#<BigDecimal:a60520c,'0.3E4',9(18)>, "supplier"=>{"name"=>"amazon.com"}, "account"=>{"code"=>"SF-Marketing-Indirect", "account_type"=>{"name"=>"Ace Corporate"}}, "currency"=>{"code"=>"USD"}, "payment_term"=>{"code"=>"Net 30"}, "shipping_term"=>{"code"=>"Standard"}, "commodity"=>{"name"=>"Marketing-Services"}}]}}

mystruct = DeepStruct.new hash
mystruct.requisition_header.requested_by.login # => coupasupport
mystruct.requisition_header.to_h # => {"requested_by"=>{"login"=>"coupasupport"}
```

Comment: Seems, I am not clear in the question..mystruct.requisition_header.requested_by.login will give coupasupport, but my aim is to generate those keys and store them in an array. Those array of keys I will be using to search in different hashes. I will be searching keys in different hashes with https://github.com/chengguangnan/vine

Comment: I'm still not clear about your expectation, could you please update your question and elaborate with example?

Comment: Hi Sharvy Ahmed. I am expecting an algorithm that takes a hash which is deeply nested with hashes and arrays as values inside it and generate a direct access to for each and every value in the hash.. eg: a = {b: {c: d:{ e: 'f'}}} then the value f can be accessed by key b.c.d.e

Answer (score 0):

You could use [BasicObject#method_missing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing):

**Code**

```
class Hash
  def method_missing(key,*args)
    (args.empty? && key?(key)) ? self[key] : super
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
hash = { animals: {
           pets: { dog: "Diva", cat: "Boots", python: "Stretch" },
           farm: { pig: "Porky", chicken: "Little", sheep: "Baa" }
         },
         finishes: {
           tinted: { stain: "Millers", paint: "Oxford" },  
           clear:  { lacquer: "Target", varnish: "Topcoat" }
         }
       }

hash.finishes.tinted.stain
  #=> "Millers
hash.animals.pets.cat
  #=> "Boots"
hash.animals.pets
  #=> {:dog=>"Diva", :cat=>"Boots", :python=>"Stretch"}
hash.animals
  #=> {:pets=>{:dog=>"Diva", :cat=>"Boots", :python=>"Stretch"},
  #    :farm=>{:pig=>"Porky", :chicken=>"Little", :sheep=>"Baa"}}
```

**Reader challenge**

There is a potential "gotcha" with this approach. I leave it to the reader to identify it. My example contains a clue. (Mind you, there may be other problems I haven't thought of.)